# How to get attributes from line-polygon where points are snapped on, into the point-layer?

Tags: qgis, arcmap, point, line

I have a SQL Server spatial table with point-objects, the points are set by snapping onto a line SQL Server spatial table. so the points are georeferenced on the line.
How can I get the attributes from the line-table where the points are snapped on, 'joined' on the points?

I can temporarily make shape-files from the spatial tables, that's no problem.

I'm using QGis 2.x but I could use ArcMap 9.x too.

Answer (score 1):

The QGIS NNJoin plugin should be able to help you, but it will generate a new point layer and not update your existing point layer.  See https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/NNJoin/ and http://arken.nmbu.no/~havatv/gis/qgisplugins/NNJoin/.

Use your point layer as "Input vector layer" and your line layer as "Join vector layer".  The result is a new point vector layer that contains both the point attributes and the attributes of the nearest line plus a new attribute that contains the distance between the point and the line (should be 0 in your case).